# best way to check if is digit in specific base in C

Tags: c, radix, digit

I know that `ctype.h` defines `isdigit`, however this only works for base 10. I'd like to check to see if a number is a digit in a given base `int b`.

What's the best way to do this in C?

### Edit

I've come up with the following function:

```
int y_isdigit(char c, int b) {
        static char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        static int digitslen = sizeof digits - 1;
        static int lowest = 0;
        int highest = b - 1;

        if(highest >= digitslen)
                return -1; /* can't handle bases above 35 */
        if(b < 1)
                return -2; /* can't handle bases below unary */
        if(b == 1)
                return c == '1'; /* special case */

        int loc = strchr(digits, c);
        return loc >= lowest && loc <= highest;
}
```

Is there any advantage to using the version schnaader made to this? (This seems to have the added benefit of not relying on the user's charset being ASCII—not that it matters much anymore.)

Comment: What "digits" are allowed in base 99?

Comment: @Mark: some very unrecognisable characters!!!

Comment: The digits allowable are those _you define_ to be allowable... there is no standard set of allowable digits except for `b<=10`, `b=16` & `b=64`, you could extrapolate between `b=10` and `b=36` using the alphabet, but past there it is completely arbitrary

Comment: The base will always be less than 36.

Comment: "The base will always be less than 36" - ah, that old homework problem.

Comment: I'm mainly a database guy nowadays. Whenever I hear someone say something like "The whatever will *always* be . . .", my first thought is, "No, it won't." Followed quickly by, "And it's probably not even true now."

Comment: This actually isn't homework, just me trying to learn some C.

Comment: So it's self-assigned homework. ;) That's fine. It's not a bad thing. But learning doesn't happen when we hand you the answer--if you're trying to learn a language, it's better to be led to the solution (and to have you find it yourself) because that way you understand the process that gets you there.

Comment: I corrected your code to make it compilable, at least - but it's still not correct (eg. `strchr()` does not return an `int`, it returns a pointer to the character if found, or `NULL` otherwise).

Comment: @aharon: What about lowercase letters?  Are those valid digits, and do they have the same value as their uppercase counterparts?  Also, it might be advantageous to move your code into an answer so we can vote and comment on it separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
// input: char c
if (b <= 10) {
  if ((c >= '0') && (c < ('0' + b))) {
    // is digit
  }
} else if (b <= 36) {
  if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) {
    // is digit
  } else if ((c >= 'A') && (c < 'A' + (b - 10))) {
    // is digit
  }
}
```

This should work (untested) for base 2..36 if you're using `0`..`9` and `A`..`Z`.

An alternative would be to use a boolean lookup table, this is the fastest way to check. For example you could prepare tables for bases 2..36, using up 256*35 = 8960 bytes of memory, after this the `isdigit` check is a simple memory read.

Comment: Oh, I think you want <= '9', not < '9'

Comment: Why are you assuming that the letters are contiguous? You should probably state that as a restriction.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks, that was a copy and paste error. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @pax: OK, assuming ASCII here, but can this be different as we are talking about the C type `char` here?

Comment: The underlying character set is ASCII in probably 99.99% of the machines out there. Unfortunately (for me), I do some work on one of the _others_ :-) z/OS USS uses EBCDIC as its underlying character set and ISO specifically states that only '0' thru '9' can be assumed to be contiguous.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Wow, nice to know. That's why "Never assume anything" is one of the best programming quotes.

Comment: @schnaader, @paxdiablo: In any case such complicated nested `if`-`else` constructs make not much sense, here. Don't think you'd be smarter than your compiler for such things. The `switch` statement is made for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using conventional bases (e.g. octal or hexadecimal) you can use `strtol()` to convert and check for an error condition. if you are using arbitrary bases, e.g. base 99 there may not be an out of the box solution.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of `isdigit` is that it is usually a macro that expands at compile time. There is also another one `isxdigit`.

If you'd want to do the same for your own convention of digits you could go for an `inline` function that would be almost as good:

```
inline
bool isdigit42(char c) {
  switch (c) {
    default: return false;
    case '0': return true;
    case '1': return true;
    .
    .
  }
}
```

Your compiler would know best of what cases can be shortened because the characters are in a common range of values. And in case that this is called with a compile time constant character this should be completely optimized out.

Comment: If base `b` can be between 2 and 36, you'll get to lines like `case '7': return (b > 7);` which is still fine, but I'd prefer to write/check/maintain some nested `if` statements instead.